# What is the impact of DocuSign if migrating On-Premise SharePoint system to SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

I'd like to know the consequences if DocuSign was migrated from On-Premise Sharepoint to Sharepoint Online; if there's any at all. Any response is highly appreciated! As I am a new user to DocuSign and new to it being implemented in Sharepoint.

I hope this is the right place to ask!